# How to write a mongo template query criteria for following query

Tags: mongodb

{ $and: [ { Expression1 }, { Expression2 }, { Expression } ] }
or
{ { Expression1 }, { Expression2 }, { Expression }}

Comment: Would be helpful if you can give us a sample dataset, expected output and sample of the custom query that you would be working on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.